# Monobehaviour can not find a member OfType in Unity

Tags: c#, unity

This is the line where I am getting above mentioned error:

```
var listeners = FindObjectOfType<MonoBehaviour> ().OfType<iPlayerRespawnListener> ();
```

I have already imported these libraries including `System.Linq` which has the above mentioned method `OfType`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;
```

Where is it going wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on OP's answer: the crucial difference is the use of `FindObjectOfType` versus `FindObjectsOfType`.

- `FindObjectOfType` returns a single object.
- `FindObjectsOfType` returns an array of objects.

Linq's `OfType` extension method requires an enumerable collection (such as an array), which is why you were seeing that error and why switching calls fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by changing `FindObjectOfType` to `FindObjectsOfType`:

```
var listeners = FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour> ().OfType<iPlayerRespawnListener> ();
```

Comment: Why are you not just looking for objects of type iPlayerRespawnListener? Are there non-MonoBehaviours that have it as a component?